# Invalide instance in App.root How can i fix this?

Tags: kivy

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

---

I'm currently watching a youtube tutorial on kivy, but I keep getting this app.root error, what does it mean and how do I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        return MyGrid
```

You need to return an *instance* of a widget class, not the class itself:

```
return MyGrid()
```